# Get the first date (max date) available joining a table ranked ASC based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the set of data below which I created to emulate what my live data looks like. I am trying to pull the LATEST standard costs based on date ascending from a standard cost CTE where the dates considered are only those which are before the inventory transaction date. What I have so far is this, which works but is not very efficient based on the execution plan.

```
CREATE TABLE stdcosts
(item varchar(20) not null,
indt date not null,
rev integer not null,
[MC00.010] money default 0,
[OC00.000] money default 0,
[GC00.025] money default 0,
[MS00.010] money default 0) ;

 INSERT INTO stdcosts
VALUES
('201226-03','02/26/2019',1,2000,0,100,50),
('201226-03','09/07/2019',2,700,0,0,50),
('201226-03','10/07/2019',3,500,0,20,10)

CREATE TABLE inventoryOH 
(item varchar(20) not null,
 warehouse varchar(8) not null,
 TransDate date not null,
 seq integer not null default 1,
 owner varchar(10) ,
 project varchar(10),
 orderID varchar(10),
 onHand integer default 0,
 Age bigint,
 costMethod varchar(15) ,
 WVG_flag varchar(1),
 WVG char(4),
  rowno int );

 INSERT INTO inventoryOH
 VALUES
 ('201226-03','B','6/18/2019',1,'','','NPO312979',5,134,'STANDARD','N','',1),
 ('201226-03','B','9/3/2019',1,'','','NPO315960',14,57,'STANDARD','N','',2),
 ('201226-03','B','9/23/2019',1,'','','SFC037624',1,37,'STANDARD','N','',3),
 ('201226-03','B','10/1/2019',1,'','','NPO316472',6,29,'STANDARD','N','',4);
```

Output:

```
SELECT i.*, s.*
FROM inventoryOH i
LEFT JOIN stdcosts s
    ON s.item = i.item
    AND s.indt <= i.TransDate
    AND s.rev IN (SELECT MAX(s1.rev)
                     FROM stdcosts s1
                      WHERE s1.item = s.item
                      AND s1.indt <= i.TransDate)
```

I am wondering if anyone has a way to optimize this using either a rank/row number or additional method(s) to make this run faster.

link --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b4865/2

Comment: What are the indexes on these tables? Primary key?

Comment: inventory on hand - item, warehouse, trans date, seqn, stdcosts - item, rev

Comment: Maybe toss the indexes and primary keys into your script? Just listing the columns is really not all that helpful.

Comment: "... from a standard cost view..." So you don't have a table, you have a view?

Comment: it's not a view in my query it's a CTE. I made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to perform the lateral join.

For each row in `inventoryOH` we need to find one row from `stdcosts`, that has the same `item`, that has `indt` on or before `TransDate` and that has the maximum `rev`.

```
SELECT
    inventoryOH.*
    ,Costs.*
FROM
    inventoryOH
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            item
            ,indt
            ,rev
            ,[MC00.010]
            ,[OC00.000]
            ,[GC00.025]
            ,[MS00.010]
        FROM stdcosts
        WHERE
            stdcosts.item = inventoryOH.item
            AND stdcosts.indt <= inventoryOH.TransDate
        ORDER BY
            stdcosts.rev DESC
    ) AS Costs
;
```

To make it work efficiently you should create an index in `stdcosts` table on `(item, indt) include (rev, [MC00.010],[OC00.000],[GC00.025],[MS00.010])`. The order of columns in an index is important.

I'm not sure what should be the logic around the `rev` values, but if you need the latest row based only on `indt` (not on `rev`), then sorting should be by `indt`: `ORDER BY stdcosts.indt DESC`. It would also work more efficiently with the suggested index.